# In javascript creating hash and accessing in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a hash in java script and passing it to controller through Ajax request but
in controller i'm getting hash in string

```
{1100:{time:\"1\", mark:\"1\", difficulty_level:\"3\"}, 1108:{time:\"1\", mark:\"1\", difficulty_level:\"3\"}}
```

I have tried using `JSON.parse` but getting error `JSON::ParserError: 710: unexpected token at`

Comment: It's not json, it's a js object. Check your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find a way to create a proper JSON from your JavaScript object, by using some JavaScript library (such as [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)), and `JSON.stringify(myObject)` . JSON requires all string-values (keys and values alike) to be surrounded by quotation marks.

So in your case, the proper JSON would look like this (non-quote escaped):

```
{1100:{"time":"1", "mark": "1", "difficulty_level": "3"}, 1108:{ "time":"1", "mark":"1", "difficulty_level": "3"}}
```